# Access hash value in each loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on a Rails API that creates shared links for users. The input accepts a JSON hash that looks like this:

```
{
    "shared_with":{
        "1": "someemail@example.com",
        "2": "anotheremail@example.com"
    },
    "expiry": "30 June 2017"
}
```

When it hits the controller it iterates through the emails that were submitted, creates the DB entry, and triggers a mailer for each. This is the controller action:

```
def create
  @user = current_user
  @recipients = share_params

  # save and mail in one step

  # first iterate over the email addresses sent
  @recipients[:shared_with].each do |recipient|

    # assign a token
    @token = Share.generate_token

    # save record, token, expiry
    @user.shares.create!(
      token: @token,
      shared_with: **???**,
      expiry: @recipients[:expiry]
    )

    # trigger mailer for email
    ShareMailer
      .share_dealsheet(recipient, @user, @token)
      .deliver_now
  end

  json_response(:created)
end
```

Everything is saving correctly and the mailers are being generated, but I can't figure out what to put in `shared_with:` to get the current email in the loop.

Comment: Just put `recipient` and try

Comment: This pull the number out rather than the email. From saved record in console: `shared_with: "2"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is error in your json (comma is missing).

```
{
    "shared_with":{
        "1": "someemail@example.com",
        "2": "anotheremail@example.com"
    },
    "expiry": "30 June 2017"
}
```

Now change your code to :

```
@recipients[:shared_with].each do |key,recipient|

    # assign a token
    @token = Share.generate_token

    # save record, token, expiry
    @user.shares.create!(
      token: @token,
      shared_with: recipient,
      expiry: @recipients[:expiry]
    )

    # trigger mailer for email
    ShareMailer
      .share_dealsheet(recipient, @user, @token)
      .deliver_now
  end
```

Comment: Perfect, works great, thank you! Fixed the missing comma above, was just a copy paste error